# Selenium webdriver - click() succeeded but didn't actually happend

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I use selenium grid (to run test on 4 browsers: FF13, FF16, IE9 and chrome. each browser is on different machine.
In the relevant section of the test, i find a clickable element and click on it.
On FF13, IE9 and chrome it works just fine: element was found and got clicked.
On FF16, the element was found and webdriver "claims" that it clicked on it, but the action of the button (changes the layout of a table on the page) doesn't happen.

note: I use version 2.25
thanks,
Tizki

Comment: Do you have a piece of code we can reproduce this with?

Comment: Is it possible that you hit something similar to [this Selenium bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3602)? Is the offending element on the edge of the screen, overlapped by a statusbar/scrollbar/whatever?

Comment: i forgot to mention that the application is GWT based. the button that i'm trying to click on is a div with static id.                        i use  element = driver.findElement(By.id("button-id")); element.click();   i don't think that the element id overlapped, at least it doesn't seems like it is.

Answer (score 2):

hmm... I would use a cheat like js injection (in case support of jQuery is included). e.g.

```
String cssSelector="...blablabla....";
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
    stringBuilder.append("x.click()");
    js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

**2nd approach (solution):**
try to find your element to click on using DOM model using `document.getElementsByTagName`   - this will return an array of found elements and you can easily find needed element using command line in firefox.
So your element be like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName[n]
```

where is n - the order of your element in found array `document.getElementsByTagName`

below code of method I use with parameters tagName - name of tag which you look for your element by, and argNum is a number which you should to subtract from the whole length of  array `document.getElementsByTagName` to get n - the order of your element :

```
public void jsDirectClickUsingDOM_GEBTagName(String tagName,int argNum) throws IOException {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 stringBuilder.append("document.getElementsByTagName(\'"+tagName+"\')[document.getElementsByTagName(\'"+tagName+"\').length-"+argNum+"].click()");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

this should work anyway. Hope it comes clear for you:)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried your solutions, but it still doesn't work with FF16, seems to me like a webdriver issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem of compatibility of `webdriver` with `FF16`. I am stuck to `FF 13.0.1` due to same reasons. By the way, I could not find any matrix of compatibilities between Firefox and webdriver, but after many times trying to run tests on different versions of Firefox, I decided to stuck to the one which really works.